# Can't access idtoken using google play plugin for unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am using the google play games [plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) and I set up everything correctly (I'm assuming). I've ran tests and I was able to log in properly. I then tried to get the user's  email, id token and access token using the example from the plugins page:

```
Debug.Log("Local user's email is " +  ((PlayGamesLocalUser)Social.localUser).Email);
Debug.Log("AccessToken is " + ((PlayGamesLocalUser)Social.localUser).accessToken);
Debug.Log("IdToken is " + ((PlayGamesLocalUser)Social.localUser).idToken);
```

I am able to get the email and access token, but the id token doesn't work. I would have thought either they all work, or they all don't. I've tested putting debug.logs before and after getting the idToken alone, nothing happens after attempting to get it.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: did you create a web app linked to your game?  The web app's client id needs to be added to the configuration in the Unity plugin in order to access the this information.   The log will also have meaningful messages on what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I put a client id in, but it was the one for the game, not the web app. I put in the right one and it works now.